# fetch details from google-calendar-API without account linking

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

What I want to accomplish is, considering I have all the required tokens (accessToken, refreshToken, authorization.. etc) but without Account linking, is there any possible way to fetch the details from the google-calendar-API using Node.js, I've already tried using the quickstart code give [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs). It does the job perfectly but with account linking.

I know this question sounds weird, but what I think is that even if I've all the required tokens for fetching the data from the google-calendar-API (resource server), how will the request know from which account the data is to be fetched. will there any accountID in the tokens which will request the data to that particular account only.

please share your thoughts.
correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Edit: By account linking I mean, entering account credentials and logging in

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by account linking?

Comment: @DaImTo [clarified] (https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) for your reference

Comment: Thats logging in not account linking

Comment: Then what's the different between account linking and logging in ?

Comment: Check wall of text update on my anwser

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I understand your issue.

When a user logs in and grants your application access to the Google calendar api.  An access token and refresh token are granted to you.  The refresh token will only work with your client id there by denoting your application to google.   The access token and refresh token are also granted by a specific user and will only be able to retrieve data for that user.   The user in question also granted your application access to their google calendar data that means that the access token will only be usable by your application to access google calendar data not for example google drive data.

The claims stored within these tokens tells google which application is accessing data on behalf of which user.

If you want to access a users information on Google then you need them to login and consent to your access of their data.  this is called authentication and authorization.

Account linking is something completely different.

**Account linking**

Lets say i have a website on our website we have our own user system where users create accounts they are stored in the database.  Users have a login and password on our system which they use to login.

Now what if we want to offer our users the option to login with their Facebook and google accounts.   If they do this they would probably end up creating a whole new account.   Or we can allow account linking

Account linking is a way of associating a users login on one system with the users login on another.  So when the users logs in with their google account we know its John Snow from our user database is also The King of the North on Google.   The accounts are linked.  So i know when ever The King of the North logs in with his Google account that its actually the user on our system named John Snow.

Technically: I have only done this with asp .net core but here is how it works.  John Snow logs into our system.  We give him a button to connect his Google account.   John clicks the button and logs in to Google.  Google returns a user id for The King of the North which I associate with John Snows user id on our system.

**Open Id**

Account linking is more open id as its `Authentication`.   The person doing the action has typed in their login and password and authenticated them self.

**Oauth2**

Oauth2 is your access token and refresh token which are used to gain access to an API.  This is refereed to as `Authorization` you are authorized to access data but the one using the access token and the refresh token is not necessarily the user who is sending the request to the api.